# Python grid world inncorrect depth first search algorithm implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, search, gridworld

I'm trying to write a depth-first search algorithm that will find a path form where the agent (black cube is) to the exit at the bottom of the right-hand path. But the algorithm I have written loops back on itself as part of the path found. How do I implement a DFS algorithm that doesn't do this?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated, please.

Thanks
**What the world looks like:**

[image: The world/maze.]

**The result of the depth first search path planning:**

[image: Output/result of path planning]

**My code for the agent class:**

```
class Agent(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, location, endPoint, world): 
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("black")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
    
        # Variables
        self._bump = 0
        self._location = location
        self._endPoint = endPoint
        self._world = world
        self._map = dict()
    
    def dfs_paths(self, start, goal, path=None):
        if path is None:
            path = [start]
        if start == goal:
            yield path
        for next in self._map[tuple(start)] - set(path):
            yield from dfs_paths(next, goal, path + [next])
    
    def _planPath(self, node, visited=None):
        if visited is None:
            visited = [node]
        self._map[tuple(node)] = self._world.testDirections(node)
        if node not in visited:
            visited.append(tuple((node)))
            print("Visited = " + str(visited))
            for neighbour in self._map[tuple((node))]:
                print("Neighbour = " + str(neighbour))
                if neighbour == self._endPoint:
                    visited.append(neighbour)
                    print("Here 1...")
                    return [node, neighbour]
                else:     
                    path = self._planPath(neighbour,visited)
                    if path:
                        print("Here 2...")
                        return [node] + path
```

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you. [MRE]

Comment: I'm not asking for it to be dubbged, I don't know how to implement a depth first search where it doesn't loop back on itself.

Comment: That _is_ asking for it to be debugged. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @MahmoudYassine if you track the visited nodes, it should be easy to prevent a cycle

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I believe I am tracking the visited nodes with the variable "visited" in the _planPath function.

Answer (score 0):

You are building the path from the `visited` information. But that does not represent the path. It just represents the nodes you have visited, which includes unsuccessful paths from which you have already backtracked.

When you find the target node, you should instead create a (partial) path with just the end node in it, and return that to the caller. The caller can detect from the return value of the recursive call that the target was found and can then prepend its own node to that partial path, and return that to its own caller.

That way the backtracking phase (after success) will be used to build the path.

So, to get you started, replace this:

```
self._planPath(neighbour, visited)
```

with:

```
path = self._planPath(neighbour, visited)
if path:  # success!
    return [node] + path
```

Or do an `append` which is more efficient, but then you must reverse the path at the very end.

And replace this:

```
self._world.showPath(visited)
```

with:

```
return [node, neighbor]
```

The main caller of `self._planPath` would probably do something like this:

```
path = self._planPath(startnode, [])
if path:
    self._world.showPath(path)
```

Note that for `visited` you should really be using a `set`, not a list.

Comment: When you say return that to the caller what do you mean? What is the caller your referring to please?

Comment: I refer to when in `self._planPath` it executes `self._planPath(neighbour, visited)`. Currently you don't have a return value feature there, but I am saying to let the (partial) path be the return value (or `None` if no success)

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: ive tried your suggestion and edited the code above to show you what I did. Also changed the caller but now don't get any output from the code?

Comment: Please don't change your question by adding in the elements of my answer. It makes my answer look stupid as it no longer applies to your question.